# how to group all of the characters of String into a 2d char array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I'd like to know how to group all of the characters of `String` into `char [][]`. Suppose i have a

```
String M = "x a b \n"+
                     "s d w \n"+
                     "D e f"
```

How can I group the characters of the above String into 2d char? 
The method should group characters as they are, i.e.:

```
x a b
s d w
D e f

public void  groupChars (String lines)
{
   char [][]temp = new char [3][3];

}
```

Comment: do you want to store the new line char in the array?

Comment: the output of the char[][] should be identical to the String, @Razib

Comment: Then it doesn't fit in a char array[3][3], since there is more than 3*3 --> 9 character.

Comment: String like `x a b` contains 5 characters including spaces, so description "*the output of the char[][] should be identical to the String*" doesn't match your expected result `char[3][3]`

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is this way [though i have used String array]

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = "x a b \n"+
                "s d w \n"+
                "D e f";

            String[] splitParts = s.split(" ");

            String[][] newArray = new String[splitParts.length/3][3];
            for (int i = 0, a = 0; a < newArray.length; a++) {
                newArray[a][0] = splitParts[i++];
                newArray[a][1] = splitParts[i++];
                newArray[a][2] = splitParts[i++];
            }
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(newArray));


    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[x, a, b], [
s, d, w], [
D, e, f]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole `String` `M` you given is not fit in a `char[3][3]` array, since it can contains only 9 `char`. If you adjust the size then you can do the following -

```
    int i=0; 

    for( int row=0; row<3; row++){
     for(int column=0; column<3; column++){
        array[row][column]=M.charAt(i++);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Razib! But why doesn't it fit into char[3][3]. But i only have 9 characters.

Comment: Because in this case the newline - '\n' is also considered as a `char`. Moreover your have some space in your given String. The space is also considered as a `char`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the size of the `String` beforehand, use a `List` in between. You can get the rows with [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and split each row into a character array with [`String.toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

```
String M = "x a b \n"+
            "s d w \n"+
            "D e f";

String[] rows = M.split("\n");    
List<char[]> charArrayList = new ArrayList<char[]>();
for (String row: rows) {
    charArrayList.add(row.toCharArray());
}

char[][] twoDimensional = charArrayList.toArray(new char[charArrayList.size()][]);

// test run to make sure we got it right
for (char[] row: twoDimensional) {
    for (char column : row) {
        System.out.print(column);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Note that this code excludes the newline characters from the original `String` but includes the spaces.